# Caliburn.Micro for WPF Controls Project

Tags: caliburn.micro

My current situation is that I have a winforms application which I would like to create a new WPF controls library projects to start showing new screens in WPF. I would really like to leverage the Caliburn.Micro framework but im struggling getting it set up. I currently have my bootstrapper as a Singleton so that I can initialize it and also Im setting the useApplication property in the base contructor to false. I'm not sure where to go from here any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private static AppBootstrapper bootsrapper;

    public static void InitializeInstance()
    {
        if (bootsrapper == null)
        {
            bootsrapper = new AppBootstrapper();
        }
    }

    public AppBootstrapper() : base(false)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little code from your bootstrapper how you configured it and then can you show us also how you are calling the bootstrapper with respect to the Singleton?  Just to confirm you are creating this inside of a winforms application or are you creating a new app in WPF?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have much right now but ive updated my post with what I have.